# Set the variable to public \PDO $pdo; Why are you doing this?

Tags: php, pdo

[image]

Set the variable to public \PDO $pdo; Why are you doing this?

\PDO What does this mean and why is it written like this?

Comment: As per the [ask] guide, please **do not** post pictures of your code. Code is text, there is no reason not to copy and paste it here and - if necessary - [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Pictures of code are really unhelpful, for several reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway `\PDO` is an example of a namespace. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [Typed Properties](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2), which were introduced in PHP 7.4. It is just a way to say that the variable `$pdo` should have the class `\PDO`, making sure that you can't assign any other types (like strings, arrays or other classes) to this variable. In general, stronger typing allows you to make fewer mistakes and is more easily readable to other users.

In this case, the namespace `PDO` has been imported at the top already, so that line could be replaced by:

```php
public PDO $pdo;
```